# angular application html *ngfor="ler KitapEvi of kitaplar " Can't reach. Can you help me?

Tags: angular

```
export class Kitap {
        stok_kodu:String;
        adi:String;
        aciklama:String; 
        birim_fiyat:Number;
        image_url:String;
        aktif:boolean;
        stoktaki_birimler:Number;
        tarih_olusturuldu: Date;
        Son_güncelleme: Date;
}
export class AppComponent {
  kitaplar:Kitap[]=[
    {
    stok_kodu:"text-100",
    adi:"java Programlama Dili", 
    aciklama:"Java Programlama Dilini Öğrenin", 
    birim_fiyat:600,
    image_url:"assets/images/books/text-106.png",
    aktif:true,
    stoktaki_birimler:100,
    tarih_olusturuldu:new Date(),
    Son_güncelleme:null,
  },
  {
    stok_kodu:"text-101",
    adi:"C# Programlama Dili", 
    aciklama:"C# Programlama Dilini Öğrenin", 
    birim_fiyat:900,
    image_url:"assets/images/books/text-101.png",
    aktif:true,
    stoktaki_birimler:100,
    tarih_olusturuldu:new Date(),
    Son_güncelleme:null,
  },
  {
    stok_kodu:"text-102",
    adi:"C++ Programlama Dili", 
    aciklama:"C++ Programlama Dilini Öğrenin", 
    birim_fiyat:700,
    image_url:"assets/images/books/text-102.png",
    aktif:true,
    stoktaki_birimler:100,
    tarih_olusturuldu:new Date(),
    Son_güncelleme:null,
  }
  ]
}
```

Template:

```
 <h1>KitapEvi</h1> <table border="1"> <thead> <tr> <th>Ad</th>
    <th>Açıklama</th> <th>Fiyat</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr
    *ngfor="let KitapEvi of kitaplar"> <td>{{KitapEvi.adi}}</td> <td>{{KitapEvi.aciklama}}</td> <td>{{KitapEvi.birim_fiyat |
    currency:'INR'}}</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Comment: *ngfor="let KitapEvi of kitaplar">does not reach helpp meee

Comment: Also, where is @Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
}) 
export class AppComponent {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `*ngFor="..."` with an upper case F. In your code you have `*ngfor="..."` with a lower case f.

Comment: Thank you very much. It took a lot of time. How I overlooked